# Answers to questions where a feature is not possible

Tags: discussion

My question on networkengineer is this:

[Stopping Cisco Prime/NCS from resizing maps](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/stopping-cisco-prime-ncs-from-resizing-maps/1670?noredirect=1#1670)

So it turns out the feature I'm trying to find doesn't exist. What would be the best thing to do with this question:

1. Delete it?
2. Answer it myself saying the feature doesn't appear to be available in Cisco Prime 1.3?
3. Leave it unanswered for future updates if the feature does appear?

I know this is directly related to my question, but I believe we may run into questions where such things are not possible, and I believe they would be better with an answer saying "no this can't be done" instead of deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer yourself and accept the answer.

Answering your own questions is explicitly encouraged by SE: [Answer of questions](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/answer-of-questions)

Comment: Yes, and if someone is searching for the solution to this unsolvable problem, I sure would like them to find *this* site. Saying "it can't be done" happens to be the solution in this case. No problem with that.